# What is the correct "from" header syntax?

Tags: php, email

We would like to send emails with PHP.

To have a clearer "From" display in Gmail, we would like to display some `From` text like:

```
MyDomain.com (Support)
```

There is a big problem: many email clients truncate the `From` text when some non-alphanumric characters are used (dot and bracket).

For exemple, Yahoo! Mail displays:

```
MyDomain com (Support)
```

Gmail displays:

```
Support
```

We saw that some leading websites or PHPMailer add double quotes. So we generate this header:

```
From: "MyDomain.com (Support)" <support@mydomain.com>
```

It looks to work in the email clients (yahoo, gmail, iphone, etc.) we tried. But:

1. We could not test all the clients
2. We could not find anything in the RFC
3. Many tools do not follow strictly the RFCs (some smtp can simply eat up emails)

What is your experience with handling non-alphanumeric characters? Does our header will be an issue in some clients?

Comment: The full reference is in [RFC2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), section 3.4. Good luck.

Comment: Why don't you use [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) ?

Comment: Maybe they didn't know about SwiftMailer?? seems like a silly question

Comment: The question is more related on the clients compatibility. We have already experienced "challenging" behaviors as some smtps and clients are not strictly following the RFCs

Comment: I will rephrase my question, have you tried [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) ?

Comment: @Glavić No, because it is buggy (188 open bugs), and we saw that the library is not bulletproof on handling headers: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the syntax that we used a while ago without problems.

However i would recommend you to Switch to [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

We use PHPMailer right now and are satisfied with it.

Comment: Have you seen some email clients behaving "strangely" when displaying/receiving emails with double quotes in their `from` header?

Comment: No honetly i do not think so. As far as i know we also never had a customer complaing about this. But why you do not just switch to PHPMailer? Thats a much more reliable solution.

Comment: (I rephrased my question as it was confusing. Sorry.) The syntax is valid (PHPMailer add the double quotes in the method `EncodeHeader()`), the question is more about the compatibility with clients. PHPMailer can produce valide headers but these headers may not be handled properly by the client.

Comment: No i understood it. As i said we used this mrthod a long time without any problems. And now we use phpmailer also without any problems. So it works fine.